# Drop function in clojure

Tags: clojure

Given the following function, I could not understand what map function is receiving as second parameter.

```
(def tails
 (fn [seq]
   (map drop
        (range (inc (count seq)))
        (repeat (inc (count seq)) seq))))
```

Given that seq is (list 1 2 3)

The line:

```
(range (inc (count seq)))
```

Will produce ((1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3))

And the line:

```
(range (inc (count seq)))
```

Will produce (0 1 2 3)

So, what is receiving the map function as second parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter is `seq` repeated as many times as its length + 1, so you can drop 0 to length elements from it.

For `'(1 2 3)`, you get

```
(map drop '(0 1 2 3) (repeat 4 '( 1 2 3)))
```

which (when realized) will become the equivalent of

`(list (drop 0 '(1 2 3)) (drop 1 '(1 2 3)) (drop 2 '(1 2 3)) (drop 3 '(1 2 3)))`

which evaluates to

`((1 2 3) (2 3) (3) ())`

Comment: Thank you Diego,

but I did not figured out how

    (map drop '(0 1 2 3) (repeat 4 '( 1 2 3)))

have been evaluated. Could you explain me more?

Comment: Never mind. Map can receive two sequences, then apply the function like as you mentioned. Thanks